# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor while connecting as JDBC remote client

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have gone through all the suggestions given by many of you for this query. But unfortunately none of them has fixed my issue.

Problem:- I have installed Oracle12c into a our remote machine(Host1) and by default ORCL database has created and running. After that by using Database configuration Assistant I have created new database "YILIDB". I can connect to these databases from Host1 through sqldeveloper tool. But when I'm trying to access the above databases from another machine (Host2) I can't connect to it. First I tried by using JDBC code to connect to that data base. I got the below Exception.

## Code:-

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:172.26.8.188:1521:YILIDB", "WM6",
                "WM6");
```

## Error:-

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:825)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:755)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:38)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:599)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at ConnectionTest.main(ConnectionTest.java:39)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:324)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1963)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:564)
    ... 6 more
```

And when I'm trying to connect from Host2 sqldeveloper to Host1 database I got below error which means basically I can't connect to remote database neither with JDBC code nor using sqldeveloper.

## Error while I'm trying to connect from sqldeveloper:-

> Status: Test-failed: IO error the network adapter could not establish the connection

And In the remote database machine I have verified services. Both ORCL and YILIDB services are running. I see only one listener in services up and running.

Can someone please provide me the solution for this.

Find the status of >lsnrctl status below

```
C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 25-OCT-2016 14:14:41

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER

Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production

Start Date                25-OCT-2016 14:04:56
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 9 min. 44 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           YILIDB
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Administrator\diag\tnslsnr\SMYB2SW12-Yili\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.28.8.199)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

The command completed successfully
```

Comment: The listener status shows clearly that the database instance isn't registered with the listener. This probably means that you didn't start Oracle. What do you see when you run `sqlplus / as sysdba`? Does running `alter system register` from within `sqlplus` make the listener see the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed by changing the jdbc url with @.

### Previously:

jdbc:oracle:thin:123.45.6.78:1521:YILIDB

### Now:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.45.6.78:1521:YILIDB